# Can magnets be arranged to interact with earths magnetic field to produce force?

Tags: magnetic-fields, earth

Is it possible to arrange one or more magnets along with iron/ferric guides to interact with our planets magnetic field in such a way that a force is generated in one or more directions?

Would a shape such as this create asymmetry, or would it just balance out in the end?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

what you propose has been in use for centuries- it is called a compass. Note that because the magnetic field of the earth is relatively weak, the forces it can exert on other magnets in its vicinity is very small.

Answer (score 0):

If there were enough magnets to be produced massively and they were huge and put in the hallback array then yes it would cause force. But the force would be very negligible.

Comment: if an object containing such an array was placed in orbit of earth, would it accelerate/decelerate the object?